# Connect frontend Vue JS to Laravel websocket on kubernetes

Tags: laravel, vue.js, kubernetes, websocket, service

first sorry for my english.
I need connect my frontend VueJs to my Laravel Websocket, both environment on Kubernetes, my backend deployment have two service, one service is tha API serve (it's work ok), another service to serve the websocket.
The frontend is serve on enginx and the backend is serve on apache, the frontend on kubernetes use Upstream to connect to API backend, my idea is use another Upstream to connect to websocket but not work.

My configure VueJS:

.ENV:

```
VUE_APP_WEBSOCKET='IP-websocket'
```

```
var pusher = new Pusher('ASDASD2121', {
            cluster: 'mt1',
            wsHost: process.env.VUE_APP_WEBSOCKET,
            wssPort: 6001,
            disableStats: true,
            enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
          })
```

Kubernetes service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: websocket-sitio
  namespace: sitio
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend-sitio
    tier: backend
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: websocket
    protocol: TCP
    port: 6001
    targetPort: 6001
```

My question is, ¿how configure the frontend to connecto to Laravel websocket using kubernetes service without using IP?

Help on my connection from frontend Vue JS to Laravel websocket